# jQuery Colorbox a form in popup window won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox to popup a window with an edit form but when click submit nothing happens. What actually happens is the page just reloads without submitting any data. So here is how I call the popup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemPopup').colorbox({ transition:'none', width:'90%', height:'90%'});
});
```

The form works perfectly fine outside the popup.

Can anyone share any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Provide a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I can't provide a JsFiddle because I can't simulate the situation there as the content is dynamically generated. It's a link with item id in it on click a form loads for the current item id. Everything works except it isn't submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.itemPopup').colorbox({ transition:'none', width:'90%', height:'90%'
             ,onComplete:function() { 
             $("#buttonClick").click
     }
   });

});
```

write you action in oncomplete block.